# Have an HTML element act as an anchor to stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use an `<h4>` as an anchor to stop the page scrolling?

i.e. when I scroll to  `<h4>`, you cannot scroll any further down.

Comment: Did you mean manual scrolling or programmatic scrolling ?

Comment: So, what you wanna Use in `href=""` part?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please ask in proper way. Also show what you have tried till now.

Comment: I didn't try or have anything to try. Because I simply don't know where to start.

Comment: try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/j9oxuyyu/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can add css class `cursor` property:

```css
h4 {
  cursor: pointer; /*<----this will make all the h4 elements to have hand cursor. */
}
```

```html
<h4>Acting as anchor with pointer cursor.</h4>
```